# Можно ли как то в js поменять путь svg картинки в html?

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<svg class="svgColorTheme"><use xlink:href="image/svg/all.svg#MoonTheme"></use></svg>
```

Comment: ``setAttribute``

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для этого [`.setAttributeNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS)

```js
document.querySelector('.svgColorTheme use').setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'image/svg/all.svg#SunTheme');
```

Comment: По-моему, без ns будет работать так же?

Comment: Если правильно понял из [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS#notes), то для атрибутов типо `xlink:href` необходим данный метод. Но что-то подсказывает, что не для инлайновых SVG

Comment: Просто я когда-то экспериментировал и для элементов действительно нужен был ns-метод, а атрибуты работали в любом варианте. Хотя, тут ещё и неймспейс атрибута от неймспейса тега отличается, не уверен, что я такой случай проверял.

Comment: Оба работают. Сделал сниппет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно поменять с помощью `setAttribute` или `setAttributeNS`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  var id = e.target.id
  var use = document.querySelector('use')

  if (id === 'blue') {
    use.setAttribute('xlink:href', '#' + id)
  } else if (id === 'red') {
    use.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#' + id)
  }
})
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: grid; margin: 0; }
svg { width: 100vmin; margin: auto; --cursor: pointer; }
circle { cursor: var(--cursor); }
use { --cursor: auto; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -5 19 19">
  <circle id="blue" cx="5" r="4" fill="blue" />
  <circle id="red" cx="14" r="4" fill="red" />
  <use xlink:href="#blue" y="9" />
</svg>
```